# How to get a man page for manually compiled software?

Tags: mac-osx, unix, manual, man

I'm using Mac OS X and I manually compiled [llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) because they were not available from MacPorts (a package manager).

I presume `clang` has some kind of `man` page. How do I install and/or activate it so that I can access it with `man clang`?

Comment: Minor technicality:  MacPorts has both of these available.  `sudo port install llvm-devel +clang`

Comment: Ah, thank you. `port search clang` yielded nothing - I thought it was a separate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from a Linux perspective (which I think might be reasonably similar) the manual compilaton of a program, that is, by the usual

```
make; make install
```

may have already generated a `man` page, and installed it in an appropriate place. This might be done by the makefile.

At least, I've observed this when installing Linux software.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't seem to. It looks like the "man page" is in a `docs` subdir in `.pod` format. I'll install it via MacPorts as the top comment says.

Answer (score 1):

As pavium says in my experience with Linux if a man page has been created it installs with the software when you make it.  If the authors did not create a man page they did create an on line manual.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html

Comment: Thank you. I had saw that, but as I don't manually compile FOSS often, I wondered what the general deal with `man` pages is.